# installing vlc-tar.bz2 and gcc.tar

Tags: linux, installation, vlc-media-player, tar, gcc

I need to install `vlc` player in fedora which is a `tar.bz2` file. How can i install it ?
Someone told me that *gcc* is needed to install this software. How do install `gcc-4.6.2.tar` ?

Please list the steps needed to install *vlc.tar.bz2* and also *gcc.tar* .

Answer (score 0):

gcc can be installed via the `yum` package manager, which handles all the software management in the system. Try:

```
yum install gcc
```

or

```
yum search gcc
```

But you should always try to go with a premade package; for VLC you can get it by adding the [RPM Fusion](http://rpmfusion.org) repository. The instructions for configuring it are available on [their **configuration** page](http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration).

Comment: and otherwise ?

Comment: What do you mean by "and otherwise "? The simplest way to install packages is using the ones already available in Fedora's repositories.

Comment: For the yum what do i exactly need to enter ?

Comment: I am a new user to for linux. So i am not aware of what does yum do and what is a RPM Fusion repository

Comment: I edited my answer and clarified a few things which might help.

Answer (score 0):

**Never** install **anything** from sources, if you don't know how to do it. Use [package for your distro and version](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-fedora.html) and package-manager of your system